# </br> in JTable

Tags: java, html, swing, jtable

I am trying to apply some HTML syntax to my `JTable`. However the `br` tag is not being applied. I have also tried to resize the height of the rows but that is not working. Other HTML tags work.

What am I missing?

Thanks,

Comment: "What am I missing?" You missed to give your code sample here. So, we can help.

Comment: if </br> is the only tag it is wrong defined. Do it this way <br/>

Answer (score 1):

the corret tag is

```
<br> or <br/> NOT </br>
```

Comment: This solved my question. In addition, row resize should be applied to fit the new height.